# Trouble understanding QCQP

Tags: optimization, qcqp

> Using a graphical method, indicate the feasible region and solve the minimization problem. $$\begin{array}{ll} \text{minimize} & f := x_1^2 + x_2 + 4\\ \text{subject to} & c_1 := -x_1^2-(x_2+4)^2 +16 \ge 0\\ & c_2 := x_1 - x_2 - 6 \ge 0\end{array}$$

---

I draw the problem as such:

[image: Imgur of drawn graph]

And I do understand that to be able to relate the constraints to the subject function, the function needs to be held constant. I do have a hard time understanding where the minimizer actually is.

By holding the function constant results in level curves consisting of parabolas, is the minimizer at the top of those parabolas, or have i misunderstood something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, a small mistake in your figure, the line for the second constraint does not pass through $(0,-4)$.

The function that you want to minimize is $f(x)=x_1^2+x_2+4$. Let's say the value for this is some $v$, not necessarily the minimum. We want to plot contours where $f(x)=v$. $$x_2=-x_1^2-4+v$$
These are upside down parabolas, shifted along $x_2$ axis, with the vertex on the $x_1=0$. The the figure below. The legend shows the $v$ value.

It is easy to see that the minimum of $f(x)$ given the constraints is $-4$ at $x=(0,-8)$.
[image: Figure]

Comment: Thank you for the response, and yes i admit that the drawing is a rough sketch, it is supposed to pass through (0,-4)
The problem i have though is to understand why -4 is the minimizer.
Is it because the top of the parabola intersects with the constraint, or something other than that?

Comment: All those parabolas are constant levels of $f$. If I would draw a parabola with $f=-5$ it would be lower level, but it would not be part of the domain of the constraint. So you want to draw the lowest level curve that has at least one point in the domain. In this case, the top of the parabola intersects with the domain. If I would draw a parabola with any lower level, it would not touch the circle. It is not necessary to be the top of the parabola, but it is an easy example in this case

Comment: Okay, and to get the terminoly straight, what is, in this case the minimizer, and i assume that -4 is the minimum?

Comment: Yes, you are correct

Comment: As last question, why is it that the lowest parabola gives the minimizer to the function?

Comment: It is the lowest level. I can imagine a different function, for example $g(x)=-f(x)$, where the same parabola will be the maximum. For the minimum of $g$ you would need to move up, until you get the last parabola that will touch the circle on the side.